# Cannot mirror screen on smart tv using HDMI cable and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: hdmi, screen, smart-tv

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS onto my HP Pavilion 15 gaming laptop. I tried to display the screen on my tv using an HDMI cable, but ran into some issues. Currently, when the laptop and tv are connected with the HDMI cable, it either wont send any sort of signal to the tv, or the tv will output a blank white screen that occasionally will display the background image. No icons or taskbar. Just the background.

I've tried the mirror option in settings, it goes black, then logs me out on the laptop screen and asks me to login again as if nothing had changed. I've also tried the other display settings of joined and single.

I've a dual OS setup in my laptop. Mirror display when running Windows works fine. I just don't know where to look next. Help me?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. `xrandr --listmonitors` lets you show what the system knows about your TV.